# I created a scene in blender. But when I rendered it there were no textures. Why?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials, 3d-view

Today, I created a scene in blender having glass table modeled. And everything had materials( The legs of table were steel and the 'Glass Table Top' was glass). I applied texture with Normals, Gloss, AO, etc. to the plane on which the table stands.

Render in 3D Viewport:
[image]

Materials:
[image]

I switched to rendered view in 3D Viewport and it came up excellently. But when i render it in UV Image Editor( The default render buton) The textures were missing but the materials were intact. Can Anyone pls help me out? 
The Image:[image]

BTW, My denoising Settings:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Go to FILE>External data>Pack all into .blend. Save the file. Upload the file here (under 5mb): pasteall.org    /// We need to see the file. This is a hard case. Thanks for sharing screens, but my only guess it´s there´s a pass not working on the pass tab.

Comment: It should show this: https://imgur.com/dV9fYGY

Comment: Thanks for the reply and here is the blend:http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51548